# I am using Apache POI to replace keywords in a xdoc with an answer I imported from a xls file. It only replaces one keyword and stops why? no looping?

Tags: loops, apache-poi

public static void processDRDocument(String[] fileLocation) {

```
    try {

        String line = "";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileLocation[0]));

        InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream(fileLocation[0]);
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);


        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("DocumentInforma");

        Iterator iterator = sheet.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) iterator.next();
            Iterator cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) cellIterator.next();
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                    case STRING:
                        //System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
                        break;
                    case NUMERIC:
                        // System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                        break;
                    case BOOLEAN:
                        //   System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                        break;
                }
            }

        }

        int numOfQuestions = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileLocation[3]);
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int z = 1;
        while (y < numOfQuestions) {
            question[y] = workbook.getSheet("DocumentInforma").getRow(x).getCell(y).getStringCellValue();
            answer[y] = workbook.getSheet("DocumentInforma").getRow(z).getCell(y).getStringCellValue();
            // System.out.println(answer[y]);
            question[y] = "[[" + question[y] + "]]";
            //System.out.println(question[y]);
            y = y + 1;
        }

        System.out.println(answer[0]);
        System.out.println(question[0]);
```

//TODO: Make a normal loop to replace Cat with the question and Dog with the answer array

```
        y = 0;
        XWPFDocument xdoc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis));
        //XWPFWordExtractor we = new XWPFWordExtractor(xdoc);

        while (y < numOfQuestions) {

            for (XWPFParagraph p : xdoc.getParagraphs()) {
                    List<XWPFRun> runs = p.getRuns();
                if (runs != null) {
                    for (XWPFRun r : runs) {

                        String text = r.getText(0);
                        if (text != null && text.contains(question[y])) {
                            text = text.replace(question[y], answer[y]);
                            r.setText(text, 0);
                            System.out.println(text);

                        }
                    }
                }
                xdoc.write(new FileOutputStream("output2.docx"));
                    y = y + 1;
            }


        }
    }

    catch(Exception ex){

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

### }

The String array contains a line of questions [[Who is the first president?]] and an answer row that says things like [[George Washington]]?
Doc file contains words like cat dog [[Who is the club president? ]] [[Timestamp]]

I tried looping the string array in a XWPFRun loop. I am new to apache POI any help is appreciated.

I am expecting for the code to loop through the word doc and replace all keyword questions [[question(3)]] with answers [[answer(3)]].

Comment: `XWPFDocument xdoc ...` ... `xdoc.write(new FileOutputStream("output2.docx"));` internally commits the `OPCPackage`. After that no changes to the `XWPFDocument ` are possible. Do the writing part outside the `while` loop.

Comment: The above is the main problem here. But there are many other problems while replacing text in word processing text runs. Especially Microsoft Word is very creative in how to split text into text runs because of many different and often not really understandable reasons.